# Elseif statement to not working for wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to dequeue scripts and styles for logged out users, but allowing the same scripts/styles to appear for two login pages that use those assets.

I currently have:

```
// SCRIPT AND STYLE DENQUEUE
// https://gist.github.com/DevinWalker/7621777
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_styles_scripts', 9999 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'dequeue_styles_scripts', 9999 );

function dequeue_styles_scripts() {

    if (  ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // REMOVING SCRIPTS NOT NEEDED FOR LOGGED OUT USERS

        //UM BASE STYLES AND SCRIPTS
        wp_dequeue_style( 'um_modal' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'um_styles' );

        wp_dequeue_script( 'um_scripts' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'um_members' );

    } elseif ( is_page ( array( 4425, 16771 ) ) {

        return;

    }
}
```

The logged out user conditional works, but the elseif statement isn't working. Not sure why. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: missing closed parentheses -> elseif( is_page( array(4425, 16771) ) ) {}

Answer (score 2):

You have a closing parentheses missing in the `elseif` condition.

```
elseif ( is_page ( array( 4425, 16771 ) )) {

        return;

    }
```